# decode string between special tags with htmlspecialchars_decode and preg_replace

Tags: php, html, string, replace, special-characters

i'm trying to decode strings between tow special tags with `htmlspecialchars_decode` and `preg_replace`, for example my original string is like this:

```
other strings...[link]&lt;a href=&quot;http://example.com&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;example&lt;/a&gt;[/link]other strings...
```

i need to convert everything between `[link][/link]` to html original code. tested this:

```
    $str = preg_replace("/[link](.*)[\/link]/eisU", "htmlspecialchars_decode('$1')", $str);
```

dosen't worked! i searched google and SO too but was useless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the square brackets, otherwise `[link]` is interpreted a character set comprising the letters `l, i, n, k`.

You should use `preg_quote()` if you're not sure about what to escape:

```
preg_replace('/' . preg_quote('[link]', '/') . '(.*?)' . preg_quote('[/link]', '/') . '/eisU', ...
```

This will do too:

```
/\[link\](.*)\[\/link\]/eisU
```

Comment: ya i tried to accept your answer but time was over! :-) sorry my friend. i just scored your answer.

Comment: @Vahid I didn't mean before the timer is up lol ... you can accept it now :)